# Angular BehaviorSubject servis not changing in other component

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-services

I have a service that has BehaviorSubject from rxjs.

We have two variables

```
  private coordinatesSourceLat = new BehaviorSubject<any>("test");
  private coordinatesSourceLng = new BehaviorSubject<any>("test2");

  currentCoordinatesLat = this.coordinatesSourceLat.asObservable();
  currentCoordinatesLng = this.coordinatesSourceLng.asObservable();
```

After that, I call a method that changes these two coordinates(lat and lng):

```
  changeCoordinates(lat: any, lng: any) {
    console.log("0. servis changeCoordinates, coordinates are: ", lat, lng);
    this.coordinatesSourceLat.next(lat);
    this.coordinatesSourceLng.next(lng);
  }
```

So now, in the **first component**, I implement the service and put:

```
//this is first component
     coordinatesLat:any;
     coordinatesLng:any;

  ngOnInit() {

    this.sightService.currentCoordinatesLat.subscribe(coordinates => this.coordinatesLat = coordinates);
    this.sightService.currentCoordinatesLng.subscribe(coordinates => this.coordinatesLng = coordinates);
    console.log("1. SightInfo coordinates are: ", this.coordinatesLat);

  }
```

And I add a function that changes the coordinates, in the **first component**:

```
  getSightCoordinates(){
    console.log("getSightCoordinates actiated");
    this.sightService.changeCoordinates(this.sight.lat, this.sight.lng);
  }
```

I call this function in the **first component**, html:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-go" (click)="getSightCoordinates()">Go</button>
```

---

### Now the `changeCoordinates` method in the service activates and changes the lat and lng. **But I cannot see that change in the second component!**

In the **second component** I also added:

```
  coordinatesLat:any;
  coordinatesLng:any;


  ngOnInit() {

    this.sightService.currentCoordinatesLat.subscribe(coordinates => this.coordinatesLat = coordinates);
    this.sightService.currentCoordinatesLng.subscribe(coordinates => this.coordinatesLat = coordinates);
    console.log("2. map coordinatesLan are: ", this.coordinatesLat);
    console.log("2. map coordinatesLng are: ", this.coordinatesLng);
  }
```

The service changes correctly but the second compoennt doesn't get that change. What am I missing here?

Comment: At this line in your code `this.sightService.currentCoordinatesLng.subscribe(coordinates => this.coordinatesLat = coordinates);` You are assigning again `coordinatesLat`. Should not that be `coordinatesLng`?

Comment: Yes, I fixed that, forgot to mention it here. @AmitChigadani

Comment: Did you also change it in second file? Can you please create a stackblitz with your problem?

Comment: do you realize your console logs are probably also executing before the subscribe has completed. How do you determine that the values are not being set?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this error by first changing the parameters to just send one object with lan and lng. In the service:

```
private coordinatesSourceLatLng = new BehaviorSubject<any>({
      lat: 43.318415,
      lng: 21.893258
 });
currentCoordinatesLatLng = this.coordinatesSourceLatLng.asObservable();

changeCoordinates(lat: any, lng: any) {
        let obj = {
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng
      }
    this.coordinatesSourceLatLng.next(obj);
}
```

The first component:

```
  getSightCoordinates(){
    console.log("getSightCoordinates actiated");
    this.sightService.changeCoordinates(this.sight.lat, this.sight.lng);
  }
```

And finnaly, the second component:

```
this.sightService.currentCoordinatesLatLng.subscribe(coordinates => {
  this.coordinatesLatLng = coordinates;
  this.getDirection();
});
  getDirection() {
    this.origin = { lat: 43.314778, lng: 21.898639 };
    console.log("blaivan", this.coordinatesLatLng);
    console.log("blaivan", this.coordinatesLatLng.lat);
    this.destination = { lat: Number (this.coordinatesLatLng.lat), lng: Number (this.coordinatesLatLng.lng) };
  }
```